# Magento 2 - Payment methods not work

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, order-success-page

When I conclude the order to the checkout, the current order is always saved in the **pending status**.
Also when I go to the success page of the order I go back the **error 500**.

The same mistake is presented to me when I try to access the payments section in the backnd. How come?
It seems that Magento2 has problems with payments.

What can I do to fix the problem?